# Derivative of average number (density) of clusters in Erdős–Rényi random graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G(n, p)$ be the Erdős–Rényi random graph model with $n$ vertices and $p\in[0,1]$. Furthermore let $\mathbb{E}_{n,p}[k]$ be the average number of clusters (counting isolated vertices as $1$). I was wondering if it is possible to say something about the asymptotics of

$$ p \frac{1}{n}\frac{d}{dp} \mathbb{E}_{n,p}[k]$$

Especially evaluated at (close to) $pn=1$ I wonder about

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{d}{dp} \mathbb{E}_{n,p}[k]$$

Will it tend to zero?

Comment: what $k$ stands for? does it indicate the size of the clusters you are counting?

Comment: Sorry I am counting.

Answer (score 1):

Given $n$ vertices, there are $f_{n,k}$ groups of $k$ vertices, where $f_{n,k} = \binom{n}{k}$.
A particular group of $k$ vertices is a $k$-cluster (i.e. every couple of vertices in the group is connected) with probability $g_{k,p} = p^k$.
The probability that there are exactly $x$ $k$-clusters is:

$$ h_{n,k,p}(x) = \binom{n}{x}g_{k,p}^x(1-g_{k,p})^{n-x} $$

The expected value of $x$ is $\mathbb{E}_{n,p,k}[x]$.
Since $x$ is a binomial random variable, then

$$\mathbb{E}_{n,p,k}[x] = ng_{k,p} = np^k$$

The expected value of the total number of clusters is:

$$\mathbb{E}_{n,p}[k] = \sum_{x=1}^n x\mathbb{E}_{n,p,k}[x] = \sum_{x=1}^n nxp^k = np^k \sum_{x=1}^n x = np^k \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = p^k \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}$$

Moreover:

$$\frac{\text{d}\mathbb{E}_{n,p}[k]}{\text{d}p} = kp^{k-1}\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}$$

You can go on now.

**Note: some edits added**

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I think we speak about different quantities. Your $\mathbb{E}_{n,p}[k]$ counts the expected number of clusters with $k$ vertices, where I actually meant the expected total number of all clusters...

Comment: @antarcticfox, you can't just sum over k? Your variable is just a sum of the_candyman's variables with $k=1,..,n$.

Comment: @the_candyman, what I didn't understand is that all the vertices must be connected. You can have a k-cluster without connect all his vertices, then the probability you gave is a lower bound to the question... Am I missing something in your argument?

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro The "group of $k$ vertices" is just a subset of $k$ vertices. A "$k$-cluster" is a group of $k$ vertices where all of them are connected to each other

Comment: @the_candyman, so suppose $p=1$. We should be able to recover that in this case there is only one $n$-cluster, right? Your result for $\mathbb{E}_{n,p}[k]$ suggests that for any $1\leq k\leq n$ we have in average $\frac{n^2 (n+1)}{2}$ clusters? Something went wrong here...

Comment: Just to make sure that we speak about the same. Under cluster I meant equivalence class w.r.t. to the equivalence relation of connectivity, i.e. existence of a path. When you speak about a $k$-cluster you mean a set of $k$ vertices with all $k(k-1)/2$ edges?

Comment: @antarcticfox exactly! Because of this I said his probability is a lower bound, once you can have a component of k vertices without all the connections.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. So we also expect that the derivative preseves order that is for $f(p) \leq g(p)$ it follows $\frac{d}{dp} f(p) \leq \frac{d}{dp} g(p)$ ?